# ui-router loggin page without menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a begginer with angular 1.6 and I would like to do the next:

Loggin, register & remember password without menu.

After loggin: Menu, nav bar and footer appears.

Up to now I have the next:

Index.html

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Loggin: Works fine.

```
 authenticationService.Login(vm.email, vm.password, function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                $location.path('/main');
            } else {
                vm.error = 'Username or password is incorrect.';
                vm.loading = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

If I have logged I go to main, here my problems appear..

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Navigation -->
<div ng-include="'../views/partials/main-navigation.html'"></div>

<!-- Page wraper -->
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <!-- Topnavbar -->
  <div ng-include="'../views/partials/main-topnavbar.html'"></div>

  hola mundo
  <!-- Main view  -->
 <div ui-view>aqui tengo que meter todas las vistas</div>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <div ng-include="'../views/partials/main-footer.html'"></div>

</div>
<!-- End page wrapper-->
```

Now I would like to put the rest of my web pages inside the main

```
<div ui-view>All pages here</div>
```

How Can I do this?

I have read several pages https://ui-router.github.io/ and some more, but It is not clear for me.

I think I have to do some in my app.js but I don't now what...

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('frontEndApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngResource',
    'pascalprecht.translate']).config(config).run(run);

function config ($stateProvider, $translateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');// app routes
    var states = [
        { name: 'main', url: '/main', templateUrl: 'views/main/main.html' },
        { name: 'login', url: '/login', templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html', controller: 'loginController', controllerAs: 'vm' },
        { name: 'department', url: '/department', templateUrl: 'views/department/department.html', controller: 'departmentController', controllerAs: 'vm' }
    ];
    // Loop over the state definitions and register them
    states.forEach(function (state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state);
    });
    /**
     * Translation of the web page with angular-Translate
     */

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        files: [{
            prefix: '../config/languages/locale-',
            suffix: '.json'
        }]
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
}

function run ($rootScope, $http, $location, $localStorage) { // keep user logged in after page refresh
    if ($localStorage.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.currentUser.token;
    }

    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var publicPages = ['/login'];
        var restrictedPage = publicPages.indexOf($location.path()) === -1;
        if (restrictedPage && !$localStorage.currentUser) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}
})();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
   { name: 'main', url: '/main', templateUrl: 'views/main/main.html' },
    { name: 'login', url: '/login', templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html', 
    controller: 'loginController', controllerAs: 'vm' },
    { name: 'main.department', url: '/department', templateUrl: 
    'views/department/department.html', controller: 'departmentController', 
    controllerAs: 'vm' }
```

If department belongs to main then call it:  'main.department'